# Importing external css and javascript file to Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms

I have a javascript file and a css file which i want to use in my angular 4 app.

I tried importing them in the `angular-cli.json` file like this :

```
  "styles": [
    "../../../bootstrap-combobox/js/bootstrap-combobox.min.css",
    "./styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../../../bootstrap-combobox/js/bootstrap-combobox.min.js"
  ],
```

But it does not seem to work. I made sure that the path of the files is correct.

Also to make this work, I need to use jQuery to assign an html element to a function, so i did it this way :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from '../../../node_modules/jquery'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-billgenerator',
  templateUrl: './billgenerator.component.html'
})
export class BillgeneratorComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".chosen").combobox();
  });
  }
}
```

Here is the html element, that i want to apply it on :

```
<select class="chosen">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong?
I recently started learning Angular, so i don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

install jQuery with npm

```
npm install --save jquery
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

add:

```
"scripts": [
 "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
],
```

and import it like this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

and use it that whay:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".chosen").combobox();
 });
```

if jQuery is propery integrated, you can import your js files